# Center DIV container both horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

**This question is not a duplicate. I tried other methods and they didn't work correctly!**

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to put a container div (600x600) right in the middle of the webpage, both vertically and horizontally.

**What is happening:**

The div only centers horizontally, but not vertically.

**What I have tried:**

I've followed a few methods. One of which puts another div outside of the container, which is set to display:table, then the container is a table cell. This didn't work.

I also just tried using this which another stackoverflow post suggested:

```
    position:absolute;
    left:0; right:0;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
```

This also did nothing for me.

**FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/ULHbt/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="largeLogo">Logo</div>
    <div id="redBanner"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background-color:#d7d7d7;
}
#container {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    top:50%;
}
#largeLogo {
    position:relative;
    top:167px;
    width:502px;
    height:40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border:1px solid;
}
#redBanner {
    top:326px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#d2232a;
    height:42px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Comment: Include top:50%; on your #largeLogo css

Comment: @Blazemonger I tried this and it didn't work for me. I did mention this in the question had you bothered to read it.

Comment: Then you didn't implement it correctly. You might have at least linked to that question, though.

Comment: @Blazemonger This is a help site is it not? I tried it, it didn't work for me, I need help working out why. Someone has now mentioned why. Also this solution breaks other parts of my design

Comment: The "other parts of your design" should likewise have been mentioned in your original question. It's unfair to the people trying to help you if their answers are rejected because you provided incomplete information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the absolute position method, you also have to set the width and height.

```
#container {
    margin:auto;
    width:600px;
    height:600px;
    border:1px solid;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ULHbt/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, But this then stops the red bar from filling the width of the page. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: Does the red bar need to be within the container? I didn't see anything about the red bar in your question.

Comment: The red bar worked fine previously, It's only stopped displaying correctly from your changes. I put the bar inside the container as it needs to stay in the same place, but stay 100% width of the body

Comment: The red bar seems affected by _position:absolute;_ of _#container_. In Chrome atleast.

Comment: I will change my layout, so the container is 100% width instead. Thanks for your help

Comment: I have set container to 100% width, and changed the redbanner to position:relative. This fixed that issue. Thanks